# Generic Static Constant

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

It's hard to explain but I basically want to be able to have an interface which my subclasses need to implement, which mandates a static constant. How would I achieve this in Kotlin?

I have the following class/interface:

```
interface BaseFragmentInterface {
  val TAG: String
}

class BaseFragment: Fragment() {
  /* this, of course, doesn't compile right now: */
  companion object: BaseFragmentInterface {}

  func<T: BaseFragment> push(fragment: T) {
    /* Here I want to access TAG */
    Log.d(T.TAG, "Push Fragment")
  }
}
```

My subclasses need to be required to implement the interface. And my base companion object would need to be somehow `abstract`.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: So I guess that your `BaseFragment` should be `abstract` right? Since in the code snippet you provided, it's `final`.

Comment: I think it is the same question as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327443/companion-objects-in-kotlin-interfaces

Comment: @Neo I have found this before. It doesn't work, unfortunately. There is no base class for this to access it the way I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me precise few things.

> My subclasses need to be required to implement the interface.

There's no way to achieve this, you can't force a subclass' `companion object` to implement your interface since the `companion object` of a class is not related to the `companion object` of its superclass.

> And my base companion object would need to be somehow abstract.

Since the `companion object` is an `object`, it can't be `abstract`, because an `object` can't be `abstract` too.

**Said that**, you have two options to still achieve your desired behavior:

1. Use `TAG` as a non-static final property inside `BaseFragment`:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
    protected abstract val TAG: String

    fun <T : BaseFragment> push(fragment: T) {
        /* Here I want to access TAG */
        Log.d(TAG, "Push Fragment")
    }
}

class FragmentImpl : BaseFragment() {
    override val TAG: String = "fragment-impl"
}
```

2. Use companion objects to hold the tag, make the type `T` of `push()` as `reified` and access the `TAG` property inside the companion object of `T` using the **reflection**.