# How interface can enforce "static" methods in sub-classes in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm implementing a customized Parcelable interface using Kotlin (Original Android's API: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Parcelable). How can I enforce a static field (i.e. companion object) similar to how the CREATOR field is enforced?

Comment: Does this answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327443/companion-objects-in-kotlin-interfaces ?

Comment: I don't think so. The code in the answer doesn't "enforce" the subclasses to implement the CREATOR. For example, if I implement that interface without CREATOR val, no error will be raised

Comment: I think it answers your question: it can't.

Comment: Then is there a way to work around that? And how did Android library manage to raise an error when I don't implement CREATOR field, assuming it can't implement such enforcements?